# Need Advice and Best Way to Remove all <p> tags inside an HTML table using Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, html-table

Im creating a simple html table and here is my example HTML source

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Address</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p>John Doe</p></td>
<td><p>Flat 7 118 Blackhorse Grove</p><p>London W6 7HB UK</p></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I'm trying to implement a Jquery script, but it wont delete all paragraph tag inside the table. e.g

Here's my code in Jquery

```
$("table").find("<p>").remove();
```

What went wrong?

Comment: Should be `$("table").find("p")`. If you look at your console, it would also tell you that their is an error.

Comment: Yes, remove angle brackets.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen i will try this and will let you know. Thank you so much

Comment: @wazz thank you i will try this solution.